# Howto configure ProGuard settings for ButterKnife 8?

Tags: android, android-proguard, butterknife

I am running ButterKnife version 8.5.1 in my Android app. If I try to make ProGuard settings for ButterKnife I still got crashes in my release version. There is an [issue on the official ButterKnife Github page](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/409) which tells you to make the following settings:

```
-keep class butterknife.** { *; }
-dontwarn butterknife.internal.**
-keep class **$$ViewBinder { *; }

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
     @butterknife.* <fields>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    @butterknife.* <methods>;
}
```

Alternatively it is written to use these settings:

```
# Butterknife
-dontwarn butterknife.internal.**
-keep class **$$ViewInjector { *; }
-keepnames class * { @butterknife.InjectView *;}
```

None of these work with my configuration. I still got crashes when accessing Views bound by ButterKnife. So are there any new settings which you need to make for ButterKnife 8?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In ButterKnife 8 the auto generated Subclasses are called different. You can handle ProGuard settings for Version 7 and 8 this way:

```
###---------------Begin: proguard configuration for ButterKnife  ----------
# For Butterknife:
-keep class butterknife.** { *; }
-dontwarn butterknife.internal.**

# Version 7
-keep class **$$ViewBinder { *; }
# Version 8
-keep class **_ViewBinding { *; }

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * { @butterknife.* <fields>; }
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * { @butterknife.* <methods>; }
###---------------End: proguard configuration for ButterKnife  ----------
```

Although I am using `@OnClick` methods I even do not need the last line. These settings work perfect for me. Try it out!

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

```
-keep public class * implements butterknife.Unbinder { public <init>(**, android.view.View); }
-keep public class * implements butterknife.internal.ViewBinder { public <init>(); }
-keep class butterknife.*
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * { @butterknife.* <methods>; }
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * { @butterknife.* <fields>; }
-keep class **$$ViewBinder { *; }
-keep class **$ViewHolder { *; }
-keep class butterknife.**$Finder { *; }
-keep class **_ViewBinding { *; }
```

If you have multiple libraries, make sure butterknife dependency is in the app's `build.gradle` file, or atleast move the `annotationProcessor` into it.